# Static analysis tool for C/C++ code with obsolete OpenGL code

Tags: c, opengl

Is there an static analysis tool that helps me upgrade an obsolete OpenGL codebase? Such as helping me sort which functions should not be used and which ones instead, as well which methods to change.

Comment: Which functions are those that "should not be used?"

Comment: You could just copy+change the GL header, marking the functions you want to avoid as deprecated (compiler specific, but available in most common ones)